# How to find the divergent behavior for a function with $Gamma$ function

Tags: convergence-divergence, gamma-function, quantum-field-theory

In a book by Jean Zinn-Justin (Phase transitions and renormalization group), there is a function
$$\Delta(x,0)=\frac{2^{d-2}}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}\Gamma(d/2-1)\frac{1}{x^{d-2}}$$, when $d\to 2$, he says the function diverges as
$$\Delta(x,0)=\frac{1}{2\pi(d-2)}-\frac{1}{4\pi}(\gamma+ln\pi+lnx^2)+O(d-2)$$, and he say the expansion of $\Gamma$ function is used ($\Gamma(1+s)=1-\gamma s+O(s^2)$), $\gamma$ is the Euler's constant ($\gamma=-\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-x}lnx\,dx$).

**I have no idea how to get the divergent behavior above.**

Answer (score 2):

$$\Delta(x,0)=\frac{1}{4} \pi ^{-d/2}\, x^{2-d}\, \Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}-1\right)$$
Take the logarithm
$$\log\big[4\Delta(x,0)\big]=-\frac d 2 \log(\pi)+(2-d)\log(x)+\log \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}-1\right)\right)$$ Let $d=2+\epsilon$
$$\log\big[4\Delta(x,0)\big]=-\epsilon  \log (x)-\frac{1}{2} (2+\epsilon ) \log (\pi )+\log \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{\epsilon }{2}\right)\right)$$ Use series expansion
$$\log \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{\epsilon }{2}\right)\right)=-\log \left(\frac{\epsilon }2\right)-\frac{\gamma 
   }{2} \epsilon+\frac{\pi ^2 }{48}\epsilon ^2+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$
$$\log\big[4\Delta(x,0)\big]=\log \left(\frac{2}{\pi }\right)-\log(\epsilon)-\frac{1}{2} \left(\log \left(\pi  x^2\right)+\gamma \right)\epsilon+\frac{\pi ^2 }{48}\epsilon ^2+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$ Now, use
$$4\Delta(x,0)=e^{\log\big[4\Delta(x,0)\big]}$$ to obtain
$$\Delta(x,0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi  \epsilon }-\frac{\log \left(\pi  x^2\right)+\gamma }{4 \pi }+\frac{6 \left(\log \left(\pi  x^2\right)+\gamma \right)^2+\pi ^2}{96
   \pi } \epsilon +O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$